# Oracle query combine 2 selects

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, pega

Hey all I am trying to combine 2 Oracle SQL queries into one. These queries are to be used in Pega. So far this is what I have come up with:

```
WITH 
  Query1 as (DELETE FROM PC WHERE PXNAME = '84461' AND PXCLASS = 'DocQuery'),
  Query2 as (DELETE FROM WORK WHERE PXNAME = '84461' AND PXWORKCLASS = 'DocQuery') 
SELECT * FROM Query1, Query2 WHERE Query1.RecordID = Query2.RecordID;
```

The original 2 queries are:

```
Query 1: DELETE FROM PC WHERE PXNAME = {.RecordID in} AND PXCLASS = {.RecordClass in}
Query 2: DELETE FROM WORK WHERE PXNAME = {.RecordID in} AND PXWORKCLASS = {.RecordClass in}
```

And so when I run it gives me this error:

> ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword
>
> 928. 00000 -  "missing SELECT keyword"
>
> *Cause:
>
> *Action:
>
> Error at Line: 2 Column: 14

SQL Guru needed :)

Comment: Oracle only allows you to delete from one table at a time.  Perhaps cascading constraints would do what you want.

Comment: Does Pega not allow you to call a procedure or pass an anonymous PL/SQL block?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try creating trigger on 1st table after delete and write delete on second table inside it.